# New window placement behavior different on 19.04

Tags: gnome, 19.04, gsettings, gnome-tweak-tool

Before upgrading from 18.10, whenever I would open a new window, it would open exactly to the top left, flush with the screen edge, like so:

[image: 18.04 window placement]

This was preferable because it made the most of my screen space. But now, new windows *always* open with some padding and do not touch the edge:

[image]

I've tried paying around with `gnome-tweaks` and `gsettings` but have not found my answer.

Edit: Additionally, even when I have "center new windows" enabled via `gnome-tweaks`, the windows are offset and not truly centered, like so:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can install the `Put Windows` GNOME extension, found [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/), and set your window placement as you desire.

**Update #1:**

From the user...

If I set both monitors at 1080 resolution, the problem is fixed. However, if the LEFT monitor is set to portrait mode and the RIGHT monitor is set to horizontal, the problem occurs. On the other hand, the problem is fixed in the opposite setup if the RIGHT monitor is portrait and the LEFT is horizontal.

I have (Nvidia) 418 drivers, which are the tested drivers for my 1060, I don't think it's driver issue because I've been able to reproduce the error on my laptop with a second monitor plugged in that uses Intel graphics only.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this affects the "center windows" option as described in my edit? I've looked into `Put Windows` but I'm trying to solve the underlying problem because my other machines with 19.04 don't have this issue.

Comment: @abdl-dev What is your screen resolution set to? Does this problem still occur if you select a different (standard size) resolution?

Comment: Yes, the problem still occurs with various resolutions. However, if I disable my left monitor and only use a single-monitor setup, the problem is "fixed". Very strangle.

Comment: @abdl-dev  1) try and set both monitors to a standard **similar** resolution, then retest, or 2) log into a different account and see if the problem occurs there (create a temporary guest account if you need to).

Comment: @abdl-dev status please...

Comment: Ah sorry, was away from desktop until now. If I set both monitors at 1080 resolution, the problem is fixed. However, if the LEFT monitor is set to portrait mode and the RIGHT monitor is set to horizontal, the problem occurs. On the other hand, the problem is fixed in the opposite setup if the RIGHT monitor is portrait and the LEFT is horizontal. It feels rather arbitrary. The same behavior occurs on a new user I have just created.

Comment: @abdl-dev are the video drivers the same for both monitors?

Comment: Yes, they're both on NVIDIA drivers.

Comment: @abdl-dev  What version drivers? 430? If not, check compatibility with your cards and install the latest to see if it helps.

Comment: @abdl-dev status please...

Comment: I have 418 drivers, which are the tested drivers for my 1060, I don't think it's driver issue because I've been able to reproduce the error on my laptop with a second monitor plugged in that uses Intel graphics only. I've decided it's just a peculiarity of Ubuntu 19.04 deep within it's source code, since it wasn't an issue on 18.10. I've wasted quite some time of this, so I think I'm just going to let it be and hope for a patch in the future.